# SyntaxError: invalid syntax al intercalar string y variable

Tags: python

En python al querer intercalar string y variable me devuelve error. ¿Cómo se debería intercalar en este caso la variable *username*?

**Código:**

```
username=input("Nombre:")
os.system('echo "Thank you 'username'" | festival --tts')
```

**Error:**

```
  File "robot.py", line 79
    os.system('echo "Thank you 'username'" | festival --tts')
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


------------------
(program exited with code: 1)
Press return to continue
```

Comment: `os.system('echo "Thank you {}" | festival --tts'.format(username))`

Answer (score 2):

Puedes fácilmente intercalar variables y expresiones en general usando **f-string**.

Un f-string en una cadena precedida de una letra "f". La cadena puede contener expresiones Python encerradas entre `{}`. Las expresiones son evaluadas y reemplazadas, produciendo una nueva cadena.

En tu caso,

```
username = "candid"
os.system(f'echo "Thank you \'{username}\'" | festival --tts')
```

con el resultado final que `os.system` recibe la cadena

```
echo "Thank you 'candid'" | festival --tts
```

Lo que va entre `{}` puede ser cualquier expresión Python valida, como

```
print(f"{a + b}")
```

lo que imprimira la suma de las variables `a` y `b`.

Comment: Gracias, pero parece que no lo considera bien. No da error, pero no lee pronuncia el contenido de la variable, sino el nombre de la variable. He puesto así: os.system('echo "Thank you \'{ username }\'" | festival --tts')

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Python tienes?

Comment: Tengo la versión Python 3.5.3

Comment: Los f-strings están disponibles desde Python 3.6 ... sorry.

Comment: Tranquilo. Gracias de todos modos. ; )

Comment: gracias @candid Moe me diste una idea para el uso de os.systems().format()